# Caching loaded webm's within Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, caching, redux, react-redux

I have a webpage using React-Redux that displays a number of short videos (as .webms and mp4s) on a loop.

Currently, this is done by the page looping through an array of strings containing URLs to the videos.

```
export const VideoDisplay = ({videos = ["https://examplevideosource.com/video1.webm","https://examplevideosource.com/video2.webm"] }, activeVidIndex = 0) => {
    return (
        <div className="VideoDisplayer">
            <video src={videos[activeVidIndex]}/>
        </div>
    );
```

However, this seems highly inefficient. Every time a new video is displayed (roughly every 3-15 seconds), a new request is put out to get the video object that was played around a minute ago. In addition, sometimes, in between one video ending and the next displaying, there is a loading delay which then displays nothing, leaving a blank space where there ought to be a video.

Is there a way to simply load all videos into the local store and then just iterate through them without needing to call the source each time?